# Get Route Path by Name React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router for routing in a project I'm working on.

I have a route: `/frozen-food/`

Now if in future I want to change that route to `/fast-food/` I have to find where `/frozen-food/` was used and replace it with `/fast-food/`

I'm thinking of creating a file named routes or links and store the links in a constant and import them where needed and by doing so I just have to update that file.

But Is there a better way to do this? maybe get route path with it's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create a const file to save your paths, and click here for the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-demo-hook-switch-alternative-forked-k8rj4).

```
const Paths = {
  USER_PATH: "/users",
  ABOUT_PATH: "/about",
  CONTACTS_PATH: "/contacts"
};
export default Paths;
```

second, use this predefined variables to create router file,

```
const routes = {
  "/": () => <Home />,
  [Paths.USER_PATH]: () => <Users />,
  [Paths.ABOUT_PATH]: () => <About />,
  [Paths.CONTACTS_PATH]: () => <Contact />
};
```

third, change the link file or nav component, eg

```
<div className="App">
<a href={Paths.USER_PATH}>Users Page</a> <br />
<a href={Paths.ABOUT_PATH}>About Page</a>
<br />
<a href={Paths.CONTACTS_PATH}>Contacts Page</a> <br />
{routeResult || <NoPageFound />}
</div>
```

Comment: For the second step, what is the usage of returning component? I have thought of this implementation can be used for someone using ```react-router-dom```. Like ```Route component={routes[Paths.USER_PATH]}```?